# Adapting log4j1 configuration to log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I have a java application that uses log4j version 1 and I want to migrate to log4j2. The configuration properties is as keeps:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,FILE,console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %l - %m%n
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${jboss.server.log.dir}/application/application.log
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %l - %m%n
log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
```

This is the xml configuration that I am coding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5p] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %l - %m%n" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="DailyLog"
                 fileName="${env:JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/log/application/application.log"
                 filePattern="${env:JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/log/application/application.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5p] %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %l - %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
              <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
            <AppenderRef ref="DailyLog"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The log files created should be:

```
application.log.2022-06-05
application.log.2022-06-06
application.log  (Today, June 7th)
```

Log4j2 version: 2.17.1

The objective is that the second configuration is equivalent to first one.

Question: Do you think the xml configuration is equivalent to configuration properties? or Is there something missing?

Post Updates:

- ImmediateFlush removed
- Wildfly path changed
- FileAppender removed
- Interval attribute from TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy removed

After post updates, it works.

Comment: You have 2 appenders in Log4j 1.x and 3 appenders in Log4j2 (the `FileAppender` is additional). Two file appenders can not have the same file name. BTW: you can use `${sys:jboss.server.log.dir}`.

Comment: Do you mean <File name="FileAppender"> is not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Remove the appender named `FileAppender`.

The main problem in your configuration is that you have two appenders that append to the same file: `${env:JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/log/application/application.log`. Log4j2 allows such a configuration **only if** both appenders are of the same type (i.e. either both `FileAppender` or `RollingFileAppender`): in this case both appenders will share a single file manager. Otherwise the configuration will probably fail.

Comment: I removed FileAppender. Then I was testing the app and I see lo4j2 didn't create application.log.2022-06-07. It keeps writing to application.log. What is missing in this case? The log4j configuration is updated in the post.